# Sending Array of Strings as URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript

I have to send an Array of strings as URLParams.

I am not getting any error on client side nor do I get error on server side. Server is expecting the array in this format :"500","600","500"
But from my client when I send the array it goes in this format: "500,600,700"

Below is the code that creates URL link.

```
const viewLinkStart = '/productdownload';
let viewLink = null;
let productIdStrArray: string[];
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('CompanyId', companyId);
params.set('marketId', marketTypeId);
params.set('view', viewType);

let isBroker: boolean = companyType === 'BROKER' || companyType == 'NONBROKER';
params.set('Broker', isBroker.toString());

if (productIds) {
  productIdStrArray = productIds.map(e => {
    return String(e)
  });
  params.set('productIds', '' + productIdStrArray);
}

viewLink = UrlUtils.constructUrl(viewLinkStart, params);
viewLink = viewLink + '&' + 'filename' + '=' +
  (encodeURIComponent(marketName) + '_Product.xls');
```

How can I achieve to send string like "500","600","800"
instead of "500,600,700". The above code generates "500,600,700" when it request reaches server.

I can not change server side code.

thanks

Comment: Which is the expected output? *"Server is expecting the array in this format :"500","600","500""* OR  *"How can I achieve to send string like ["500"],["600"],["800"]"*

Comment: Which format do you want? Your two descriptions conflict with each other

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: That API for the endpoint is not good

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is "500, 600, 500"

due to:  `params.set('productIds', '' + productIdStrArray);`

concretely, `'' + productIdStrArray`

This is making coercion, in this case, the array must be converted to a string, so the method `toString()` is called in the array, returning the string `"500, 600, 500"`.

For getting the string: `"500", "600", "500"`, do this:

`productIdsArray.join('","')`

```
if (productIds) {
  productIdStrArray = productIds.map(e => {
    return String(e)
  });
  params.set('productIds', productIdStrArray.join('","'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. When I debugged on server side, I see that it expects String[], which is in format 0="506",1="507" but with above code server gets 0="506","507". seems like I need to send multiple params for each array element?

Answer (score 0):

this `'' + productIdStrArray` will call `Array.toString` which will join the array elements seperated by a `,` in a string, instead, you should join them using `productIdStrArray.join('","')` :

```
params.set('productIds',productIdStrArray.join('","'))
```

```js
const productIds = [1, 2, 3]
const productIdStrArray = productIds.map(e => {
  return String(e)
});

const result = '' + productIdStrArray;

console.log({
  productIdStrArray: productIdStrArray.join('","')
});

console.log({
  result
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. When I debugged on server side, I see that it expects String[], which is in format 0="506",1="507" but with above code server gets 0="506","507". seems like I need to send multiple params for each array element?

Comment: You can't send an Array of strings in the url ( which the server is expecting ) , you'll have to use `POST`, or modify the server side to split the string it receives to an Array